# Firebase Cloud Functions - FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is missing

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nestjs

I have initialized a new project of [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) inside `/functions`. After I've done that, I installed:

```
npm install firebase-admin firebase-functions
```

After that, I had to link the app to cloud functions like so:

```
const bootstrap = async (expressInstance: Express) => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, expressInstance);
  await app.listen(3000); // Just for easy way to develop
  await app.init();
};

bootstrap(server);

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(server);
```

In the app, I had to use `firebase-admin` to authorize a user. And here's the problem. I assume that running `firebase serve --only=function`, it will set FIREBASE_CONFIG, while I, running `nodemon`,  won't set FIREBASE_CONFIG.

I was wondering, how can I set this variable, and what it contains, so I could know how to set it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize `firebase-admin` with a configuration. It could be explicit, when you call `admin.initializeApp(config)`, or implicit, using environment variables.

Take a look this guide for more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?hl=es-419